# Reference request: mathematical expectation of a random object in a topological space

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability

Recently I got interested in the following question: what does a mathematical expectation look like for a random object taking values in a topological space?

This turns out to be a difficult question to answer. During the process, I came across the following paper: "Mathematical expectations for probability distributions on compact groups" by Valeri M. Maksimov (published in 1980 by Mathematische Zeitschrift at the link: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01215081)

Since I do not have access to this paper in Mathematische Zeitschrift, would someone who has an e-copy share the main results and techniques of this paper (or email me a copy)? Thank you.

P.S. The title of this post is a bit inaccurate, judged by the contents above.

**Edits 1 (Oct 27,2019)** HERBERT HEYER wrote a paper "MOMENTS OF PROBABILITY MEASURES ON A GROUP" (link: https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijmms/1981/872640/cta/) that gives a notion of mathematical expectation for random objects in a group by extracting two key properties of expectation on a linear space, i.e, the expectation of a Dirac mass at $x$ should be $x$ and the expectation of a symmetric distribution (in terms of group operation) is the identity element. But I'd prefer to read the shorter one by Maksimov before diving into HEYER's 37-page long paper.

**Edits 2 (Oct 27,2019)** I can get a preview (2 pages) of Maksimov's paper from Mathematische Zeitschrift, which imposes more axioms on what an expectionn should be than did Heyer's paper. But Maksimov's classified all (compact) groups that admit an expectation. It is the techniques for this classification that I would like to learn from Maksimov's paper.

**Edits 3 (Oct 28,2019):** Our library has access to the paper and I got an e-copy of Maksimov's paper

Comment: It's hard to imagine a notion of "expected value" for anything that doesn't have values in a vector space.

Comment: @RobertIsrael : thank you for your comment. But we should not be so pessimistic about the notation of "expected value" since it can be defined for (a) random objected taking values in a metric space (e.g., as Frechet mean); (b) random objects in locally compact groups (e.g., as hinted on page 160 of by Herbert Heyer's book "probability measures on locally compact groups"; this page cites Maksimov's work mentioned in the post).

Comment: Your profile says you're a professor at a large university, so surely your library can help you get a copy of this paper.  Even if you don't have a subscription, they can almost certainly obtain it through interlibrary loan.  Talk to your librarians!

Comment: @NateEldredge : Ok. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @NateEldredge : thank you for your suggestion. Our library has access to the paper and I got an e-copy